# ASP.NET MVC binding model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Let's say I have these models :

```
public class FilterModel
{
    FilterPersonModel Person { get; set; }

    FilterJobModel Job { get; set; }
}

public class FilterPersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class FilterJobModel
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following action :

```
public ActionResult Search(FilterModel model)
{
      //TODO
}
```

And finally my action is called with the following url : http://mysite/myController/Search?Name=Bob&Age=32&CompanyName=Amazon&JobTitle=Developer

When I debug, my model is null, the Person and Job properties are not recognized.
Without changing anything, do I have to create a model binder or is there another solution?
If yes, which one?

Comment: Provide the code that was used to build the URL

Comment: It needs to be `.../Search?Person.Name=Bob&Person.Age=32&Job.CompanyName=Amazon&...`

Comment: As I said in my post, nothing must change (url, models, action)

Comment: If nothing can change then it will NEVER work so what are you asking a question for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible. *Something* must change, whether that be the URL or the action/models. Since the URL is the public interface, i'd suggest creating a view model to match that URL and then you can map over to the desired model from there. For example:

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public ActionResult Search(FilterViewModel model)
{
    var filter = new FilterModel
    {
        Person = new FilterPersonModel
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Age = model.Age
        },
        Job = new FilterJobModel
        {
            CompanyName = model.CompanyName,
            JobTitle = model.JobTitle
        }
    };

    // do whatever with `filter`
}
```

Comment: That's what I would do. The alternative would be custom model binding, but that's needlessly complex for such a simple solution.

Comment: Creating this "bastard" viewModel seems to be the easiest possibility.
Thanks